# Google analytics (api), count application data picks

Tags: c#, google-analytics

Within my pc application (WPF), i have an listbox of items.
The use is able to select an item, and then hit a "proceed" button.

Now what i would like to do, i get some statistics of this. I though of doing this trough google analytics, in a way so that when the user clicks proceed, somehow analytics get triggered to count +1 for the specific item in the listbox.

For example:
In the listbox i have "apple", "orange"  and "banana"
Lets say 10 people have the application on their computer.

After a week or so i log in to my google analytics account, and sees that in the passed week, 10x the apple was selected, 26 times orange and just 4 times banana.

Would this be possible to do trough google analytics ?
And doen anyone know how to do such a thin (or know where to find the information to make such a thing) ?
And if not possible, does anyone know an other way of doing such a similar thing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554062/how-to-use-analytics-for-desktop-applications

Comment: deskmetrics only has 3 months history (free version). but i do have an website, and google analytic is free, so i guess there should be a better solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My open source project Ga.Net should handle the logging of this type of data very easily.

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/projects/details/ga-dot-net

i specifically bring your attention to the support for Google Analytics 'events' as this sounds exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: i was just looking at you example right now:Event tracking. now, i must admit im not very deep into c# (yet). But could you help me out a bit how i should do this, in case of a listbox, that has dynamic content (so it may variate per user).