# Twitter statistics of my own application

Tags: twitter

I wrote a simple twitter client. so I need to know number of users who get an access for my application to use their accounts. Is this possible? And I need as many statistics of my application.

Comment: http://tdash.org/stats/clients 159821 clients indexed at the moment.

Comment: thanks a lot! there's nice service, but the percent of all tweets in this universe is not that statistics what I'm looking for.

Comment: One way would be to include some kind of traffic analysis in your project, like Google Analytics [Already answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554062/how-to-use-analytics-for-desktop-applications) . You can track for the most part anything you are interested in tracking. In order to really know more about your app usage you can always have a centralized statistics server, which receives info from your clients (like each time they open the application, how many times they use x feature,etc).If you're building a mobile app you can use something like [flurry](http://www.flurry.com)